# how to connect to noe4j database by neo4j-shell from localhost if there are 3 nodes and 3 edge on the host?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-shell

the ultimate aim is to do a full backup from one of the database, so i tried to connect to the database by shell and execute a query returns with everything. here is the issue :

```
/opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -path /opt/data/core01/data/databases -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf

NOTE: Local Neo4j graph database service at '/opt/data/core01/data/databases'
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands. Please note that neo4j-shell is deprecated and to be replaced by cypher-shell.
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n) RETURN n;
0 row
291 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
ls -l /opt/data/core01/data/databases
total 144
drwx------. 2 root root   39 Oct 19 09:36 certificates
drwx------. 7 root root 4096 Oct 19 09:36 graph.db
```

i tried to add the graph.db to the path, but did not work.

```
/opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -path /opt/data/core01/data/databases/graph.db  -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf
Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /opt/data/core01/data/databases/graph.db
```

i tried to connect to the server on a specific port :

```
[root@tnv-it-lora0002 core01]# /opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -v localhost  -port 7474  -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf
non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

i'm very new to this, so i appreciate any kind of help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

add these lines to the conf file :

```
# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all 
interfaces).
dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
dbms.shell.port=1337

/opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -v localhost -port 1337 -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf
```

export from shell :

```
cat /opt/data/core01/bin/export_statment.cql | ./opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -v localhost -port 1337 -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf
```

or

```
/opt/data/core01/bin/neo4j-shell -v localhost -port 1337 -config /opt/data/core01/conf/neo4j.conf -file /opt/data/core01/bin/export.par
```